# Rails: Run asset compile and server command in deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes

I have a problem. In my kubernetes cluster, I am trying to run my Rails application. I got the image loaded, but now I want to write a custom command. The default command in my Dockerfile is:

```
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "server", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

But I want to also run `rails assets:precompile` at startup for production. I tried those commands using this config:

```
command: ["bundle", "exec", "rails", "assets:precompile", "&&", "bundle", "exec", "rails", "server"]
```

But after the first command has been executed, I get the error:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task '&&' (See the list of available tasks with `rails --tasks`)
```

I also tried the following with `args`:

```
command: ["/bin/sh -c"]
args: 
  - bundle exec rails assets:precompile;
    bundle exec rails server;
```

But that results in a very long error which basicly says that the format of args is incorrect. Can someone explain to me how I can run both commands at startup?

Comment: Why can't you just add `RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile` to the Dockerfile?

Comment: Well, my rails app requires a connection with Redis. Building this docker image with the compile command in the dockerfile crashes the build because Redis is not running in github actions. Any idea how to fix that then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `entrypoint` for that:

```
services:
  app:
    build: .
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b 0
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

```bash
# entrypoint.sh

#!/bin/bash
set -e
# is this still an issue?
rm -f /myapp/tmp/pids/server.pid

# do what you have to do
bin/rails assets:precompile

# pass the torch to `command:`
exec "$@"
```

---

Also the lazy way:

```
    command: bash -c "bin/rails assets:precompile && bin/rails s -p 3000 -b 0"
```

---

You can also use `ENTRYPOINT` in *Dockerfile* and build it into the image:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

Comment: But this entrypoint does also compile assets for development right? You told me that you should definitely not do that?

Comment: Yes, I have now separated my Dockerfiles for production and development and all my problems are solved, so far as I can see now! All TS files are functioning and the app has the style from my SCSS files. Thank you so much! It took my one day to figure everything out, but now it is all up-to-date! :)

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk was gonna say just don't use volume `.:/myapp` in production image. glad we finally figured it all out.